# Merge two bower.json files

Tags: javascript, bower

I need to merge my two projects into one folder and I have two bower files that have some conflict dependencies. Copy and pasting will not work then with these conflicts. Is there any automate way to merge two bower.json files?

Comment: And how would the tool know which dependency to take? You can write a script that takes the two .json files and diffs them, but you still need a way to determine which ones to take.

Comment: @Sacho Everything. Just make sure no overlapping happen

Comment: You haven't thought this through. At any rate, try writing a script that diffs the two jsons and merges all the dependencies in one - and asking questions about that. This question is way too broad.

Comment: What is your use case? are you merging the 2 projects into one project? are these 2 related modules/plugins?